# Creating a summation formula in R

Tags: r

I am a beginner in R and I am given the following problem to code:

Let

[image]

and

[image]

be the summations I am trying to recreate into R.
Right now this is my code for the first summation (code snippet):

```
z <- 1:J
L<-1000
D<-0
for(k in z){
  for(j in D:D+L-1){
    X[k] = 1/L*sum(X[j])
  }
}
```

I had no idea how to create latex formulas in the questions so if you run the code snippets you see the formulas I am trying to recreate in R.
My question is, am I on the right path? I am not sure how to use the for loop to create the summation.

Comment: have not spent too much time on this one, but pretty sure thats the error --> `for(j in D:D+L-1)` should be changed to `for(j in D:(D+L-1))`.

Comment: It seems you have a matrix as input data. Can you please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(X)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(X, 20))`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas happy you also see it that way. Spend some time figuring that out. Feel free to comment on my solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
J <- 5
L <- 100
D <- 1  # in R we start to count at 1 (one).  (thanks to Darren)

x <- matrix(1:(L*J), nrow = length(D:(D+L-1)), ncol = J)

funXj_ <- function(j, D, L) sum(x[D:(D+L-1), j], na.rm = T)

X_ <- sapply(1:J, funXj_, D = D, L = L)
#5050 15050 25050 35050 45050
```

I believe your `x_j^t` is some sort of 2-Dimensional array. (so I took a matrix as example)

---

we're of course free to alter our borders:

`J as 4`, `D as 2`, `L as 80`

```
sapply(1:4, funXj_, D = 2, L = 80)
```

Comment: If it is a matrix I bet that `colSums(X[D:(D+L-1), ], na.rm = TRUE)` or `rowSums` will do it. (The first summation.)

Comment: we could possibly use `colSums(X[D:(D+L-1), 1:J]`. Of course the OP has the be very careful with the dimensions!

Comment: When `D = 0`, your code `sum(x[D:(D+L-1), j])` is actually `sum(x[ 0:99, j ])`. It makes a sum of row 1 ~ row 99, not 1:100.

Comment: @DarrenTsai No, R indices are 1-based, if `D` is zero, adjust its value prior to indexing. You are right in saying that one must be carefull, though.

Comment: @AndreElrico I was given a text file as input for this and the text file contained 7 different Markov Chains. What I was thinking was the J=number of chains and L=length of chains? Should I combine the 7 markov chains into a matrix?

Comment: If lengths of 7 chains are not equal, I think it's better to put them into a list.