# How to build a function with summation

Tags: r, function

I need to find a way to create a function that can work like the function **counts** described in the picture.

This is what I tried so far working with a code from an answer I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52723061/creating-a-summation-formula-in-r), but I can't work out how the elements that I see in that function can be translated to my case.

Function I need to replicate[image]

How my database looks[image]

Also, the function can actually be simplified with respect to the one above because the database already shows the total number of cites per year... Am I wrong? This is what I have so far:

```
j <- patents_grant$Company
t<- patents_grant$Year
x <- patents_grant$count

fun_counts <- function(j,t) {
  for (i in j)
  sum(x[1:M, j], na.rm = T)
}

counts_try <- sapply(1:j ,fun_counts, M=3)
```

I'm pretty sure this one must be easy to build and I just don't have the knowledge. So even if you just have suggestions on good places to look at to learn how to build functions, that would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for guidelines. To maximise your chance of getting a satisfactory answer, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) along with what you intended output to be.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi Erika, please see my answer below. If it solved your problem, please upvote and accept the answer; otherwise feel free to use the comment section to ask for additional help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you actually want to do is calculate the 5 (or 3)-year moving total of the number of patents lagged by one year and transformed with `log(x + 1)`.

I have created example data in `patent_grants`, and this is what one can do:

```r
patent_grants <- expand.grid(Company = LETTERS[1:6],
                             Year = 1990:2010)
patent_grants$count <- rpois(nrow(patent_grants), 4)
M <- 5
```

we sort the data by Company and Year, which makes it a lot easier and create the new column for the transformed moving total:

```r
patent_grants <- patent_grants[with(patent_grants, order(Company, Year)),]
patent_grants$count_avg <- NA
```

one now splits the data by Company, as the value is for each Company (this is done once for the vector of our moving total, and once for the count of the patents). For each `company_data` (ie. the number of patents sorted by value), we now calculate the moving total [the branching over the Companies is done with `lapply`].
For each year, we select the relevant data of the following `M` years with `company_data[(t + 1):(t + M)]`, remove possible `NA`-values with `na.omit`, take the sum, and calculate `log(x + 1)` which is equivalent to `log1p(x)` [the "for-each-year" part is done using `sapply`].

```r
split(patent_grants$count_avg, patent_grants$Company) <-
  lapply(split(patent_grants$count, patent_grants$Company), function(company_data) {
    sapply(1:length(company_data), function(t) {
      log1p(sum(na.omit(company_data[(t + 1):(t + M)])))
    })
  })
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! I definitely learned a lot from this. I kinda had an idea of the separate steps but no clue how to put them to work. You managed to do that flawlessly. THANKS!!!! (I can't vote the answer yet but I'll come back once I can)